# Setting another computer on the network as a web server

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, home-networking, ubuntu-server, lamp

I've just setup my home network with a single laptop setup as a server (Ubuntu Server 12.04) which I can connect and share files via ssh with from my client laptop (Ubuntu Desktop 12.04). My server folders also show up under networks where I can enter the workgroup and authenticate to access files.

For some time now though I've had LAMP set up only on my desktop which allows me to develop locally. These days I tend to following a guide such as...

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

So I have a server setup now and I want to install LAMP there and be able to access my web pages from the server device within the network. I just don't know how that differs from installing on my desktop. I could go ahead and install it on the server as I usually do but I don't know if I need to do something completely different so I can view web pages from the server on my desktop. Also, most searches for "installing lamp on a server" seem to me to be installing the web server on your local machine (the desktop, not another network computer - e.g. my server) or as a web server available on the internet which I don't want to do just yet.

What do I need to do differently in this case that I wouldn't have done before. I'm guessing doing as I've done before then typing the server's IP address in the browser isn't going to be enough (is it?). Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install the LAMP stack on the server and access your files using the IP of the server.

For example, if your workstation is 192.168.1.2, and your server is 192.168.1.3, the web server of the LAMP stack installed on the second machine will be accessible from your workstation's browser using the 192.168.1.3 IP.

Answer (score 0):

Server - a computer or computer program which manages access to a centralized resource or service in a network.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)

Your local computer can act as a server by providing access to shared resources to your local network, or to the internet.  Generally, a client workstation is more optimised to be sat in front of, have a graphical user interface, response its programs optimised for user response.

A server on the other hand will be optimised for batch processing of requests.  These requests may be in the form of sharing files through smb or http, or network information through dns, dhcp, or transfer of information through smtp, pop, imap, mapi.

You can setup server services, such as http, mail, and smb, on your workstation, or on a dedicated system.  'Servers' just tend to be more focused on sharing information.

As for working 'locally' or 'remotely' is a matter of perspective.  You can be working both remotely and locally.  For instance, you ssh to a remote system, then you are at its command line, and then working locally to that remote system.

All you need to do differently is remember that you are working on the remote system; if your server is going to available on the internet, then you need to be much more careful about security.